# How to call Java Script function on onClick ( button ) in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I would like to trigger the js function onClick from button. for some reason i am facing Function not defined.

Need to call this in JSP

```
// doUpdate function details
boolean doUpdate = request.getParameter("update")!=null;
String stateButton = request.getParameter("update");

if (doUpdate && catalogID != null && companyID != 0) {
    if(catalogManager!=null) {
        boolean success = catalogManager.updateStatus(new Integer(catalogID).intValue(),user, stateButton);
        if((stateButton.equals("Active")) && success) { 
    %>          
        <span class="TitleLevel01"><font color=green>Catalog is Activated.</font></span>
    <%
        }
        if((stateButton.equals("Active")) && !success) {
    %>
        <span class="TitleLevel01"><font color=red>Cannot activate subcatalog with Inactive parent.</font></span>
    <%      
        }
        if(!stateButton.equals("Active")) {
    %>                  
            <span class="TitleLevel01"><font color=green>Catalog is Deactivated.</font></span>
    <%      
            }
        }
    }
```

from this Form (looks like this)

```
 <form name="maintain_catalog_frm" id="maintain_catalog_frm" >
    <input type=hidden name="PID" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Inactive" onClick="return doUpdate(document.maintain_catalog_frm);" >
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you posot the javascript function as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have js in the jsp or have you included js file in your jsp?

Include your script in   in your jsp.

It looks like you have a jsp not js to execute here.

Is companyid and catalogue initialised properly?

Comment: Include it in <script>... Js here </script>

Comment: Please post the full code. I assume you understand that your js gets executed in the browser and jsp on the server. If you want a js to do something it will need a trigger and it is part of the HTML generated by your jsp.

Comment: Yes please... It seems there is no js involved

Comment: i am trying to fix the bug here, I see no JS for doUpdate function in my JSP. However, when i click on that it does it job ( i.e update the data). Where should i be looking ? or do you suggest me how to find out where is function hiding ?

Comment: You may have an include js in the head. If you open this in browser and right click view source you would find it. If you have templates or include Jsps then this js may be part of one of the other jsp. It's likely that your js is calling a jsp or submitting the form after validation or manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the javascript is still not loaded.

It could be your cache, or you could be having some wrong path to the JS file. What is the path to the JS file , and has it been downloaded?

Comment: I have included my javascript inside the same JSP

Comment: can you post how you included?